# How to make all values positive?

Tags: list-manipulation

So I have a list of data that contain both positive and negative values, and I am wondering what I have to do in order to make all the numbers positive.

Comment: You didn't say what relation those positive numbers should have to your original numbers, therefore the following is also a valid solution to the problem you stated: `1&/@yourlist` — this just replaces all entries of your list with `1`, which clearly is positive.

Comment: Redefine `Min[data]-1` as `0` ?

Comment: `Unprotect[Positive]; Positive[_] := True;`

Answer (score 14):

If you are indifferent to the way your data are made positive, then check `Abs` function out, which is defined as `Abs[x] == x Sign[x]`. It leaves zeros unchanged, but does make negative numbers positive. It then suffices to evaluate `posdata = Abs[data]`.

Comment: OH! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user4341 Please, remember to accept the answer, if it solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the list contains negative numbers, you could shift everything to the right on the number line by adding the absolute value of the smallest number plus one. This would preserve the ordering of the elements in your list.

```
d = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 20];
```

> {-2, -7, 10, 5, 5, 7, -3, 7, 2, -2, 9, -8, -1, 1, 3, -8, -6, 8, 0, 3}

```
d + (Abs@Min@d + 1)
```

> {7, 2, 19, 14, 14, 16, 6, 16, 11, 7, 18, 1, 8, 10, 12, 1, 3, 17, 9, 12}

Answer (score 0):

```
list = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 20]
```

> {8, -2, -1, -1, 10, -10, -9, -4, -2, 3, -2, -1, -8, 1, 6, 5, 0, 3, 5, -10}

When you apply `Abs[]` to a list, it will be applied to each element of that list:

```
Abs[list]
Abs @ list
```

Both return

> {8, 2, 1, 1, 10, 10, 9, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 8, 1, 6, 5, 0, 3, 5, 10}

Note: That also goes for other functions, like addition:

```
list + 100
```

doesn't add the number `100` at the end of the list, but adds `100` to each element:

> {108, 98, 99, 99, 110, 90, 91, 96, 98, 103, 98, 99, 92, 101, 106, 
>   105, 100, 103, 105, 90}